# Formal explanation for this change of integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Formally, why is true that $$\int_0^\infty \int_{x}^\infty f(x,y)dy dx =\int_0^\infty \int_{0}^y f(x,y)dx dy $$ ?

I know and understand perfectly the geometric interpretation, and with that, I´m well satisfied that this is true, but, what about the formal explanation? is a merely use of change variables theorem? or Fubinni´s Theorem? or a use of both?

Answer (score 2):

The integration is on the domain
$$
\{ (x,y): x>0, y>x \} =
\{ (x,y): y>0, 0<x<y \} 
$$

So this is just an application of Fubini's theorem with the function
$$
f(x,y)1_{\{0<x<y\}}
$$
and using:
$$
\int f(x,y)1_{\{0<x<y\}} dx = \int_0^y f(x,y) dx\\
\int f(x,y)1_{\{0<x<y\}} dy = \int_y^\infty f(x,y) dy
$$